# What is this circuit gain when set is in [0,1]?

Tags: circuit-analysis, gain

When set is 0 or 1 I could find it. It either attenuates by 10 or amplifies by 10. However, the circuit becomes different when it is between 0 and 1.

[image: circuit]

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Well, I don't disagree with you. But it's still physics :P
Thank you, I will post there. :) I didn't know that there is that forum.

Answer (score 2):

No, the pot has nothing to do with gain, at least not DC gain.  Note the capacitor in series with the wiper.

To analyze this, first look at what happens to DC.  Hint: All capacitors become open circuits then.

Now note that the pot adjustment only effects frequency response.  With the wiper all the way to the top, Cs and Re2 are acting on the input signal after the 30 kΩ resistor.  With the wiper all the way at the bottom, Cs and Re2 are action on the feedback signal, so the effect will be the inverse of what it was on the input signal.

Now remember that the rolloff frequency of a R-C filter is F = 1 / 2πRC.  When R is in Ohms, C in Farads, then F is in Hz.

From the above you should be able to get a pretty good intuitive idea what this circuit is intended to do, and with the equation, get a good idea at what frequencies it does it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm interested in the AC behaviour. When the pot changes, so does the voltage on the op amp then it changes the gain. I just don't know how to work with the circuit when Pot != 0 and Pot != 1.

Comment: @Yuri: Start by figuring out the frequency response when the pot is set to each end.

Comment: @Yuri: In addition to O.Lathrop`s recommendation it could be helpful to find the loop gain for both cases. Remember: The closed-loop pole frequency (3-dB corner) is the frequency where the loop gain is unity.

Answer (score 0):

> What is this circuit gain when set is in [0,1]?

For midband AC, with the pot at 0, the gain is approximately 9.09.

For midband AC, with the pot at 1, the gain is approximately 0.099.

> However, the circuit becomes different when it is between 0 and 1.

Very true - it slews the gain over an approximate range of 100:1

Comment: Thank you. Can you show me how to solve it? I've tried for a lot of time but I just can't get it right.

Comment: Try drawing out the two circuits with the pot at the two extremes. That's how I imagined it when I figured it out. Once you do that, it becomes obvious but, I guess, if you asked john Mcenroe why people couldn't play tennis he'd say something I would not write down here. The problem is, I don't know your strengths and weaknesses so I don't know how to pitch any possible answer but, if you want an answer then draw out the two scenarios and add them to your question as an addensum thing.